# How to merge ext4 partition containing data with unallocated partition?

Tags: linux, partitioning, filesystems

I'm installing Windows to update my BIOS. I've removed  a previous partition but I can't merge free partition to my original partition. How to solve this problem? I don't want to format the  ext4 partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution would be using [gparted live CD](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php).

Boot up with this Live disk, and follow the instructions to extend the partition.

See also [Features](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/features.php).